# Images are not shown in the List

Tags: android

Images are not shown in the List.In parent class i have used setImage() and getImage() but i dont know how to get images in ExpandableListMain(which is MainActivity)

```
 private ArrayList<Parent> buildDummyData(String result) throws JSONException {
    // Creating ArrayList of type parent class to store parent class objects
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
     ArrayList<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < json.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject obj1 = json.getJSONObject(i);
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("" + i);
      // parent.setImage(obj1.getImage("image"));----->this line shows an error
        parent.setText1(obj1.getString("name"));
        parent.setChildren(new ArrayList<Child>());
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("" + i);
        child.setText1(obj1.getString("name"));
        child.setText2(obj1.getString("mobile"));
        child.setText3("hellooo");
        child.setText4(obj1.getString("blood"));

        //Add Child class object to parent class object
        parent.getChildren().add(child);
        list.add(parent);
    }
    return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the image url from your server and use that url to load image into your listview. For loading image you can use any library project like
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
https://github.com/facebook/fresco